# oracle cursor parameter as collection

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

it works like:

```
create or replace procedure back_end_proc(p_rc OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) is
     v_script   VARCHAR2(4000); begin
     v_script := 'select sysdate data from dual where ''a'' = :a union all select sysdate-1 data from dual where ''b'' = :b';
     open p_rc  for v_script using 'a','b'; end;
```

when calling the procedure:

```
DECLARE
rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
 BEGIN
victom.back_end_proc2(:rc );
END;
```

will have an output rows:

```
 DATA
    27.06.2017 11:25:02
    26.06.2017 11:25:02
```

THE QUESTION IS:

how to modify the `using 'a','b'` params into one array or some collection data that will contain `'a','b'` as one string or smth like one single value?

Comment: Not clear yet. Could you plz elaborate more

Comment: What is the purpose of your query `select sysdate from dual where ...`?

Comment: is just an example using 2 input params which are hardcoded; Trying to figure how to pass to `using` params not directly but from an array or a collection!

Comment: Still not clear. Do you then also like to use the entire collection in your query? For me it does not make sense to put values into one variable (i.e. collection) but then use individual values inside the query.

Comment: variables to be bind one by one by position from collection

Answer (score 0):

If your target query looked like this ...

```
select * from whatever
where id in ( .... )
```

it would be quite simple to pass a collection.

```
create or replace type tt1 as table of varchar2(1);
/

create or replace procedure back_end_proc(
     p_ids in tt1
     , p_rc OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) is
begin
     open p_rc for 
         'select * from whatever
          where id member of :1'
         using p_ids;
end;
```

However, your posted case is slightly more complicated because you want to assign specific values from the collection in each sub-query. This means you need to use a VARRAY because that is the only collection type which guarantees ordering. So:

```
create or replace type va1 as varray(10) of varchar2(1);
/

create or replace procedure back_end_proc(
     p_ids in va1
     , p_rc OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) is
begin
     open p_rc for 
         'select sysdate from dual where ''a'' = :1
          union all
          select sysdate-1 from dual where ''b'' = :2' 
         using p_ids(1), p_ids(2);
end;
```

Comment: I figure that method with array but I need one single param which will contain all arguments for the select or at least number of params to be generated dynamically (you don't really know how much parameters there are in array)!

Comment: Your **posted code sample** has a fixed number of parameters, one per sub-query. So if you requirement is different please edit your question to make it clear. So what happens if there are say three arguments or one?

Comment: that's why the question been posted! to replace all fixed parameters with just one `using` (only one parameter after `using` clause) that will be able to send values to all listed parameters in `v_script`

Comment: Yes but what does the **query** look like with a variable number of arguments?

Comment: I'll repeat myself: 
 
**variables to be bind one by one by position from collection**

Comment: Please don't repeat yourself. We have read what you've written already: what we need is for you to revise your explanation so we can understand what it is you're trying to achieve.